# "user-defined type not defined" compile error in VB6 API declaration

Tags: vb6

Why do I get a "user-defined type not defined" error when attempting to compile the following API declaration?

```
Public Declare Function RegQueryInfoKey Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias _
  "RegQueryInfoKeyA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal lpClass As String, _
  ByRef lpcbClass As Long, ByRef lpReserved As Long, ByRef lpcSubKeys As Long, _
  ByRef lpcbMaxSubKeyLen As Long, ByRef lpcbMaxClassLen As Long, _
  ByRef lpcValues As Long, ByRef lpcbMaxValueNameLen As Long, _
  ByRef lpcbMaxValueLen As Long, ByRef lpcbSecurityDescriptor As Long, _
  ByRef lpftLastWriteTime As FILETIME) As Long
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you haven't declared the `FILETIME` UDT.

In VB6, it's declared as:

```
Type FILETIME
  dwLowDateTime As Long
  dwHighDateTime As Long
End Type
```

Comment: Thanks for adding that, but if people can't use the API Viewer to look up simple things then there's no hope at all for them.

Comment: I think it is clear that the OP didn't know to use the API viewer. So Deanna's addition is both useful and warranted.